# How to do an efficient search

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I've a big database (50gb) in which I want to search for specific lines by inputing a word that is contained in a line.
This is my command:

```
type *.txt |find /i "word_to_find" >> C:output_location.txt
```

But it takes a lot of time, stressing my SSD and CPU. Is there any more efficent way to do this using powershell?

Comment: Use `findstr` instead of `type + find`

Comment: This is cmd/batch, not powershell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to use [JScript](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/hbxc2t98(vs.85).aspx) instead, that load and run much faster than PowerShell:

```
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then

@echo off
type *.txt 2>nul | cscript //nologo //E:JScript "%~F0" >> C:output_location.txt
goto :EOF

rem End Batch section and start JScript one:
@end

var fileContents = WScript.StdIn.ReadAll(),
    search = /.*word_to_find.*/gi, match;

while ( match = search.exec(fileContents) ) {
   WScript.Stdout.WriteLine(match[0]);
}
```